# Take the max overlap date range

Tags: sql, date, impala

I have a table that has 3 columns from where i need to get max date range for a particular cust_id.

cust_id     from_date                  to_date

101  2018-08-03 00:00:00   9999-12-31 00:00:00

101  2018-08-05 00:00:00   2021-02-01 00:00:00

101  2018-08-01 00:00:00   2019-02-01 00:00:00

::expected result in impala::

id     from_date                  to_date

101  2018-08-03 00:00:00   9999-12-31 00:00:00

Can someone please help me for this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try a `LIMIT` query using an ordering by the date difference of the to and from dates:

```sql
SELECT cust_id, from_date, to_date
FROM yourTable
WHERE cust_id = 101
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(to_date, from_date) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

To find the max difference records for *all* customers, we can use `RANK`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id
                             ORDER BY DATEDIFF(to_date, from_date) DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT cust_id, from_date, to_date
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you @tim. Sorry, i slightly update the table. If there is present other date ranges that are not overlapping, will be present in the output. if we take rnk=1, I guess all other date ranges will be omitted.

Comment: You totally just changed your entire question.  I won't update my answer unfortunately.  Good luck!

Comment: Can someone please help? @tim apology